# Loading listview Activity takes long and show black screen before appear

Tags: android

I created app that takes JSON with `AsyncTask` from server. When User click a button app starts new Activity and download data from server and show it as a items in `ListView`. The Problem is when I open new `Activity` it takes too long to load. When button is pressed app freeze on about one or two seconds and then show black screen for another 2/3 seconds. After that activity is displayed but it is very slow. It freeze every time user is scrolling or pressing button to display more options of custom adapter. Is there any way to make app more smooth? Json data that is downloaded is just simple `JSONArray` with `JSONObjects` that has 2 string values and one HTML format. This 3 values is display to user.

**Part of Custom Adapter class**

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        SuggestionList suggestionList = getItem(position);
        int actualPosition = 0;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sugestion_list, parent, false);
        }
        final Button suggestionsButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggestionsMore);
        final TextView suggestionNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sugestionNumber);
        final TextView suggestionDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggestionDescription);
        final ImageView bio = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sugestionBio);
        final ImageView block = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sugestionBlock);
        final ImageView call = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sugestionCall);
...
        final Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slideup);
        final Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slidedown);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        suggestionsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (bioSuggestions.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    bio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    block.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    call.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bioSuggestions.startAnimation(slideUp);
                    blockSuggestions.startAnimation(slideUp);
                    callSuggestions.startAnimation(slideUp);
                } else if (bioSuggestions.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    bioSuggestions.startAnimation(slideDown);
                    blockSuggestions.startAnimation(slideDown);
                    callSuggestions.startAnimation(slideDown);
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            bio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            block.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            call.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, 300);
                }
            }
        });

        if (actualPosition != position) {
            if (bio.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                bio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                block.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                call.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            actualPosition = position;

        }

        JSONObject jsonValSuggestions = new getSugestions().sugestionsDetails(position, "suggestions");

        try {
            final String name = jsonValSuggestions.getString("client_name");
            final String num = jsonValSuggestions.getString("client_number");
            final String description = jsonValSuggestions.getString("client_description");

            bio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent suggestionsDetails = new Intent(view.getContext(), SuggestionsDetails.class);

                    suggestionsDetails.putExtra("client_number", num);
                    suggestionsDetails.putExtra("client_name", name);
                    suggestionsDetails.putExtra("client_description", description);
                    activity.startActivityForResult(suggestionsDetails, position);


                }
            });

            block.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent suggestionBlock = new Intent(view.getContext(), BlockSuggestionsActivity.class);

                    activity.startActivity(suggestionBlock);

                }

            });

            call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent suggestionCall = new Intent(view.getContext(), CallSuggestionActivity.class);

                    suggestionCall.putExtra("client_number", num);
                    suggestionCall.putExtra("client_name", name);


                    activity.startActivity(suggestionCall);

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (suggestionList.suggestionName.equals("null") || suggestionList.suggestionName.equals("")) {
                suggestionNumber.setText(suggestionList.suggestionNumber);
            } else {
                suggestionNumber.setText(suggestionList.suggestionName);
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                suggestionDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(suggestionList.suggestionDescription, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
            } else {
                suggestionDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(suggestionList.suggestionDescription));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("exception", e.getMessage());
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

**Part of AsyncTask class**

```
 public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";

    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String clientUrl = params[0];

        String result;

        String inputLine;
        JSONObject obj;
        String data;
        String message;

        try {
            URL myUrl = new URL(clientUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
            connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            connection.connect();

            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);

            }
            reader.close();
            streamReader.close();
            result = stringBuilder.toString();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }

public String[] getSuggestionsList() {

    String[] suggestionList = new String[5];
    String result;
    String status;
    JSONObject listObj;
    String suggestionsData;
    JSONObject suggestionsDataObj;
    JSONArray suggestionsDataArr;

    String ClientsSugestionsUrl = "https://example.com/token=" + authToken;

    getApiClientSugestions getSugestionsFromApi = new getApiClientSugestions();

    try {
        result = getSugestionsFromApi.execute(ClientsSugestionsUrl).get();

        try {
            listObj = new JSONObject(result);
            status = listObj.getString("result");
            suggestionsData = listObj.getString("suggestions");
            suggestionsDataArr = new JSONArray(suggestionsData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            suggestionsDataArr = null;
            status = null;
        }

        suggestionList[3] = status;
        suggestionList[4] = suggestionsDataArr.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return suggestionList;
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class CallsSuggestionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calls_suggestions);
        Slidr.attach(this);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Skontaktuj się");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        CallsSuggestionList();
    }

    public void CallsSuggestionList() {

        final ListView suggestionList = findViewById(R.id.sugestionList);

        final ArrayList<SuggestionList> suggestionArray = new ArrayList<SuggestionList>();
        SuggestionListAdapter suggestionListAdapter = new SuggestionListAdapter(getContext(), suggestionArray, this);
        String[] suggestionListArray = new getSugestions().getSuggestionsList();

        String suggStat = suggestionListArray[3];
        String arrayList = suggestionListArray[4];

        String clientName;
        String clientNumber;
        String clientDescription;

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(arrayList);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                clientName = explrObject.getString("client_name");
                clientNumber = explrObject.getString("client_number");
                clientDescription = explrObject.getString("client_description");

                if (suggStat.equals("true")) {

                    SuggestionList suggestionList1 = new SuggestionList(clientName, clientDescription, clientNumber);

                    suggestionListAdapter.addAll(suggestionList1);
                    suggestionListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    suggestionList.setAdapter(suggestionListAdapter);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("exception", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            clientName = null;
            clientDescription = null;
            clientNumber = null;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**SuggestionList**

```
public class SuggestionList {

    public String suggestionNumber;

    public String suggestionDescription;

    public String suggestionCallType;

    public String suggestionName;

    public SuggestionList(
//            String suggestionCallType,
            String suggestionName, String suggestionDescription, String suggestionNumber) {
        this.suggestionNumber = suggestionNumber;
//        this.suggestionCallType = suggestionCallType;
        this.suggestionName = suggestionName;
        this.suggestionDescription = suggestionDescription;
    }

}
```

`Adapter` are custom with custom view displayed to user. I use similar custom adapter to show content from sqlite that is on phone and there app isn't so slow. But when I open this activity it slow down dramatically. Also I noticed when I press back button it take very long to back to previous screen.

Comment: Post your Class file from where you are calling adapter class.

Comment: @Naveen I add SuggestionListAdapter to last listing "Activity". I also updated post and add standard SuggestionList class.

Comment: Please paste the whole class.

Comment: @Naveen I updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `getSuggestionsList` function. in this function, you are calling `getSugestionsFromApi.execute(ClientsSugestionsUrl).get();` which make your code sync again. I mean your code is waiting this code to be executed.

One way (not right way, but easy way): you can call  new `getSugestions().getSuggestionsList();` in a new thread.

Second way, call `getSugestionsFromApi.execute(ClientsSugestionsUrl)` without `get()` function. But to get result of the code, you need to give an interface.
To get right usage: https://xelsoft.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/asynctask-implementation-using-callback-interface/

Comment: Thank you! It works! I used second option with implementing interface.